# Passing a value from outer for to an inner for using jsRender

Tags: jsrender

if I do the following:

```
{{for Items}}
{{>Id}}
   {{for messages}}
       <div class="myclass">
          {{include tmpl="#myTemplate" /}}
       </div>
   {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

then at the top of my item I correctly see the value of Id

if I now remove {{>Id}} since I've proved this is what I want

I now want to add it to my div such that it becomes:

```
<div class="myclass" productid="{{:Id}}">
```

however the Id value doesn't get set against my productid attribute I've since tried {{:Items.Id}}, {{:parent.Id}} plus a few others to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can get to "parent data". See https://www.jsviews.com/#parentdata. For example you can do

```
{{for messages ~parentId=Id}}
   <div class="myclass" productid="{{:~parentId}}">
      {{include tmpl="#myTemplate" /}}
   </div>
{{/for}}
```

or you can step up through the 'array' view of `{{for messages}}` and get to the parent 'item' view of `{{for Items}}`, using `{{:#parent.parent.data.Id}}`. (See https://www.jsviews.com/#views)